# How to get all the attribute routing collections in asp core web api 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to get all the attribute route collections. to validate against my list of scopes configured in appsettigs whether the user has got the access.
I am trying to include the validation as part of the Authentication.

```
[HttpGet("test/policymethod")]
public IActionResult PolicyMethod()
{
    return Ok();
}

[HttpGet("test/check")]
public IActionResult CheckWithAuthentication()
{
    var services = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetAllService<IAuthenticationService>();
    return Ok();
}
```

How would I get above Route details?. I know we can do it using "AuthorizationHandler".However, in my case I need a different approach.

Any other option to retrieve all the Route values in asp core web api 2.0?

This is something I achieved using AuthorizationHandler and action names.I need
route collection or action names without using the AuthorizationHandler.

I am trying to include the validation as part of the Authentication. Please suggest a workaround.

```
public class ScopeAuthorization : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Scopes { get; }

    public ScopeAuthorization(IEnumerable<string> scopes)
    {
        Scopes = scopes ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(scopes));
    }
}

public class ScopeAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ScopeAuthorization>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ScopeAuthorization requirement)
    {
        var resContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;
        if (resContext?.ActionDescriptor is ControllerActionDescriptor descriptor)
        {
            if (requirement.Scopes.Contains(descriptor.ActionName))
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: fyi: If you're have checking action name against scopes, you're doing it wrong. Scopes are not there for fine-grained access control but for coarse-grained access to resources (like `orders`, `profile`). For fine-grained ACL you need to implement your own system

Comment: Expanding on what Tseng wrote, imagine that you have something like: `[HttpGet("user/history/{date}")][Scope(Scopes.UserPrivateData)] pub void meth1() {} ..... [HttpGet("user/profile")][Scope(Scopes.UserPublicData)] pub void meth2() {} .... [HttpGet("user/profile/settings")][Scope(Scopes.UserPrivateData)] pub void meth3() {}`